# Match literals with 'regex_replace' Ansible filter

Tags: regex, ansible

I cannot find a way to much a literal (a dot) in Ansible's regex_replace filter. Here is the task:

```
- name: Display database name
  debug:
    msg: "{{ vhost | regex_replace('(.+\.)(.+)$', \\1) }}"
  tags: [debug]
```

My intention is to match and replace the whole URL like **test.staging.domain.com** with its first part (**test** in the example).

Ansible would report the following error:

```
debug:
  msg: "{{ vhost | regex_replace('(.+\.)(.+)$', \\1) }}"
                                     ^ here
```

> We could be wrong, but this one looks like it might be an issue with
>   missing quotes.  Always quote template expression brackets when they
>   start a value.

How can I match literals in Ansible `regexp_replace` filter?

Answer (score 13):

it's actually possible to escape literals with double backlashes:

```
- name: Create database name and username
  set_fact:
    db_name: "{{ vhost | regex_replace('([^\\.]*)\\.(.+)$', '\\1') }}_stg"
```

The regexp above works correctly. The first capturing group extracts the first part of the URL until the first dot, the whole regex captures the whole URL. Passing **test.staging.domain.co**m through it would produce just **test**.

Answer (score 4):

There could be something whacky about escaping characters, but there's an escape-less way to code a literal dot:

```
[.]
```

So your regex could be written

```
(.+[.])(.+)$
```

Most characters lose their special meaning when in a character class, and the dot is one of them.

Comment: So simple and useful

Answer (score 4):

I was trying to do the same thing, ended up doing it like this:

```
- name: Set hostname (minus the domain)
  debug: msg={{ inventory_hostname | regex_replace('^([^.]*).*', '\\1') }}
```

*edit, found a nicer way:

```
- name: Set hostname (minus the domain)
  debug: msg={{ inventory_hostname.split('.')[0] }}
```

Comment: The `.split` solution looks sleek!